# Algorithmic Number Theory Problem - related to Matrix Multiplication Complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, nt.number-theory, algebraic-complexity

Let $F(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{i}x^{i}$, $G(x,y) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n_{x}-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n_{y}-1}a_{ij}x^{i}y^{j} \in \mathbb Z[x,y]$ with $a_{i},a_{ij} \in [0,p-1]$ for some prime $p$. Let $F(q) = f_{q}$, $G(q,r) = g_{qr}$ for distinct primes $q,r \ge p $.

$a_{i}$ can be got from $f_{q}$ by mod $q$, subtraction, divide by $q$ operations. But the technique will fail for $g_{qr}$.

$q=5$, $r=7$, $p=3$. $G_{1}(x,y)=xy$, $G_{2}(x,y)=x^{2} + 2x$. $G_{1}(q,r) = 35 = G_{2}(q,r)$ - [Wadim Zudilin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4953/wadim-zudilin).

Can knowing $G(x,y)$ at more pairs $(q_{k},r_{k})\_{k=1}^{m}$ where $p^{n_{y}} > q_{k} > p$ and $p^{n_{x}} > r_{k} > p$ help? - [Gerhard Paseman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3455/gerhard-paseman1.).

$(1)$What is the minimum such $m$? Does $m$ depend on $n_{x}$ and $n_{y}$?

$(2)$What is the algorithm to extract $a_{ij}$?

For $H(x_{1},\cdots,x_{t}) \in \mathbb Z[x_{1},\cdots,x_{t}]$,

$(A)$What is $m_{t,n_{x_{i}}}$ - the minimum number of tuples, one should evaluate $H(x_{1},\cdots,x_{t})$?

$(B)$What is the algorithm to extract the coefficients?

$(C)$Is the growth in $m_{t,n_{x_{i}}}$ logarithmic or linear or polynomial with respect to $t$ and $n_{x_{i}}$?

$\underline{Note}$: $m=1$ is trivially possible if one of $r$( or $q$) is greater than $p^{n_{x}}$( or $p^{n_{y}}$) and the other less than $p^{n_{y}}$( or $p^{n_{x}}$) but both greater than $p$.

I am facing a major hurdle in a critical step in matrix multiplication. If I can control the prime size to be of similar size, if $m$ is independent of $n$ or behaves logarithmically or linearly with $n$, and if I can extract the coefficients using mod operations quickly, then I have a chance of showing matrix multiplication is in $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ complexity. My hurdle is in the bivariate case ($t=2$). I posted the generalization for arbitrary $t$ as well as the problem generalized.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42846/shorter-version-of-computational-number-theory-problem

Comment: apart from the formatting nightmare this question is, it sounds like this is a cross post from MO. please add in the link to the original post.

Comment: Motivation would help. Tell us why we should care.

Comment: added the motivation in the end.

Comment: Please stop asking one question at more than one place at the same time.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42740/computational-number-theory-problem

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I'm not sure why this is an issue in general, as long as the cross-posting is transparent.

Comment: @arnab: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231

Comment: ok thank you Tsuyoshi

Comment: How do I close this?